# How does Unreal Engine 4 stores script in final game build?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, game-development

When i develop ue4 game game i write c++ scripts for all required logic. Then unreal engine build tools generate some additional .h and .cpp files based on my scripts. But what happens to my sctipt when final game was built? Are they stored in dll? Or they become part of game executable? And can someone somehow dissasembly my scipts and see game logic in them?

Comment: C++ isn't a scripting language. The translation units are compiled into the executable.

Comment: @vandench so all my c++ classes becomes part of exectutable, not dll?

Comment: Which DLL do you think they would end up in? If you have configurations for building an external DLL, then they may very well end up in there. By default the C++ files for the main program should end up being linked together in the `*-Win64-Shipping.exe` file.